# Date conversion is always nil in iPhone 24hr date format

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, nsdateformatter

i trying to convert string to Date which is properly working in 12hr date format. when i switch the device date format to 24, its always returning nil. Please check the below code

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let date = formatter.date(from: "6:00 am")
```

Comment: Please change dateformat to "H:mm a"

Comment: @JitendraModi No, do not. `H` is 24-hour. Why would you use 24-hour time format and am/pm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html):

> if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences.

So, to prevent date from being interpreted using device's regional settings you need to set `locale` property of your `DateFormatter`

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let date = formatter.date(from: "6:00 am")
```

Note: it's important you set `locale` before you set `dateFormat`